# Why does secondary hard drive IO slow down the entire system?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd

I have a two-drive setup: an SSD drive for Windows and apps (C:) and D: drive for code and databases. I noticed that while running an IO-intensive operation on the D drive (SSIS), the entire system becomes very sluggish and unresponsive.

The CPU usage is very low and there is plenty of free memory, but the D drive has very high IO. The C drive, however, is not doing much. Is the bus the bottleneck?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a pagefile.sys on that drive?

Comment: The page file is on the C drive.

Comment: databases should be also stored on a SSD.

Comment: It's a dev machine, I cannot justify an extra $1000 for two SAMSUNG 840 drives to replace my current 2TB one.